# Force dependabot to scan my github repo without open PRs

Tags: github, dependabot

I have dependabot enabled in my GitHub repo.

However there is currently no open PR by it.

I in my repo the following message

> Dependabot updates are paused
> We noticed you haven't used Dependabot in a while, so we've paused new pull requests for you. Merge a Dependabot pull request to resume automatically creating Dependabot updates or disable security and version updates. See open Dependabot pull requests

How can I force dependabot to run/scan my repo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by [fbiville](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277128/fbiville) in reply to [Akae Beka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15041111/akae-beka) yesterday, and to complete Akae Beka's answer: You need to go to: **Insights > Dependency Graph > Dependabot**, and from there click on "**Recent update jobs**."

You should then see a "**Check for updates**" button on that page.

See screenshots of [the "Recent update jobs" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chaHW.png) and [the "Check for updates" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuC9R.png).

Answer (score -1):

To manually run/scan the dependabot, go to **Insights > Dependency Graph > Dependabot.**

[Github Dependabot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8JBi.png)

There you will be able to see your dependencies and the logs of the dependabot executions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still no option to trigger a Dependabot run, though? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I couldn't tell you, I think that once configured it will perform the scan based on what is declared in your dependabot.yml file.

Comment: I was able to trigger Dependabot by following the path above. Then click on "Recent update jobs" and you should see a "Check for updates" call to action.